# I can't mount an ISO in Windows Server 2012

Tags: mount, iso-image, windows-server-2012

When I try to mount an ISO on Windows Server 2012 I get a message that states "Sorry, there was a problem mounting the file"... and that's it.

I Googled a bunch, and every answer to this question I managed to find is that the ISO file is flagged as Sparse. I un-sparsed the file, confirmed with fsutil that it's not sparse, then try to mount again and get the same message.

Comment: Is this any ISO, or just one specific one?

Comment: I don't have any other ISOs to test with, but copies of that same ISO do exhibit the problem.

Comment: Then most likely the ISO is just corrupt. Get another ISO from someplace and try it.

Comment: Have you tried a third-party tool, such as free 7-Zip, to open the ISO image? If 7-Zip (or Pea-Zip) can open it, then the issue is with Windows, if not, then the ISO is at fault.